# How to set an Icon in the Content Element Wizard of typo3 EXT: gridelements

Tags: typo3

How can i set the Icon of an Grid Element (Wizard)

It seems that there have been some changes because the way i did it before doesn't work anymore.

I found nothing about that in the documentation

typo3 Version 7.LTS / Gridelements 7.0.5

```
tx_gridelements {
overruleRecords = 1
setup {
    TB_3col {
        title = Drei Spalten einfach
        description = (33-33-33; 50-25-25; 25-50-25; 25-25-50) (12er Grid)
        topLevelLayout = 1
        icon = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icon/grid.png
        config {
            colCount = 3
            rowCount = 1

            rows {
                1 {
                    columns {
                        1 {
                            name = Spalte 1
                            colPos = 101
                        }

                        2 {
                            name = Spalte 2
                            colPos = 102
                        }

                        3 {
                            name = Spalte 3
                            colPos = 103
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the solution. `icon` is switched to `iconIdentifier`

```
tx_gridelements {
overruleRecords = 1
setup {
    TB_2col {
        title =Zwei Spalten einfach
        description = (50-50; 66-33; 33-66; 75-25; 25-75) (12er Grid)
        topLevelLayout = 1
        iconIdentifier = default-icon
        flexformDS = FILE:EXT:fred/Configuration/FlexForms/Grid/TB_2col.xml
        config {
            colCount = 2
            rowCount = 1

            rows {
                1 {
                    columns {
                        1 {
                            name = Spalte 1
                            colPos = 101
                        }

                        2 {
                            name = Spalte 2
                            colPos = 102
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

add the Icon in `ext_tables.php`

```
$iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class
);

$iconRegistry->registerIcon(
'default-icon',
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\BitmapIconProvider::class,
['source' => 'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Images/CE/myicon.png']
);
```

Comment: Actually icon has not been switched to iconIdentifier but both are possible. So you can either register your icon and use the identifier or you can add an icon directly and the registry will be done under the hood for you.

Comment: @Joey: Nope, not possible. 'icon' is deprecated and definitely doesn't work in v7.6.15 anymore, only iconIdentifier can be used. What a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread in the issue tracker of Gridelements to get some examples. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/73198

You can either use the icon identifier or the path to another icon file but not both.
The icon identifier can only be used, when you officially registered the icon with the icon API methods of the core.
Setting the identifier will always override the path in iconFile, since registered icons are the recommended way to handle icon files in TYPO3.

For Gridelements itself this is done i.e. in ext_tables.php

```
$iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
$iconRegistry->registerIcon('gridelements-default', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class, array(
    'source' => 'EXT:gridelements/Resources/Public/Icons/gridelements.svg'
));
```

Rules are:

You can provide *iconIdentifier* and *iconIdentifierLarge* yourself, but then you have to register the icon beforehand and any icon file you provided in the setup will be ignored.

If you provide an icon file in the setup with *icon* and *iconLarge*, the identifiers are generated automatically, so you should not set them manually.